# How to implement Expand/Collapse by gestures over an android Drop down menu/layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I want to implement a feature about expanding a drop down menu or window by sliding finger down and then collapsing it by releasing or sliding up my finger up over an android layout just like this [image: this].

I've no idea how to do that. I had searched many platforms i.e. Stack overflow, Google, GitHub etc. But unfortunately, I didn't find even a single example or piece of code. If any one owns an idea about this please recommend me any material or helpful link(s).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for [Collapsing Toolbars](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/).

This will give you the desired look - the top portion of your layout will expand when you scroll down and will get minimize when you are scrolling up.

Now that you know what you need to implement you can find a lot of guides on the subject like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTYuLho5_rE), [this from the material design](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/) and many more.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is [Bottom Sheet view](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/)
You can find different tutorials to implement it [here](https://medium.com/android-bits/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066) and [here](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-bottom-sheet-7e9cfcec6427)

Answer (score 0):

You can use animation to show-hide view from top to bottom. Below is some sample code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_img"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:tint="@color/blackColor"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp" />



    <View
        android:id="@+id/hiddenView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black_translucent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        layout="@layout/slider_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menu_img"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

slider_menu is your own layout that you want to show in slider
And below is code for java:

```
hiddenView = view.findViewById(R.id.hiddenView);
ImageView menuIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.menu_img);
menuIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
                topToBottomAnimation(slider);

            }
        });


    hiddenView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hideViewAnimation(slider);
        }
    });
     public void hideViewAnimation(View view) {
        Animation hideView = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.swipe_up);
        view.startAnimation(hideView);
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        hiddenView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }



     public void topToBottomAnimation(View view) {
            Animation showView = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.swipe_down);
            view.startAnimation(showView);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            hiddenView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

here swipe_down & swipe_up are xml file in anim folders:

swipe_up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="200"
android:fromYDelta="-100%"
android:toYDelta="0%" >
</translate>
```

swipe_down:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="300"
android:fromYDelta="-100%"
android:toYDelta="0%" >
</translate>
```